# Arrange array of dictionaries for equal distribution

Tags: objective-c

I have array of dictionaries, it looks like that :

Every dictionary N :

```
name: some name
date: some date
size:some size
category: category // * * *
```

Now i have `x` types of categories inside a dictionary ,  and 300 or more dictionaries in the array .

I have to create a new array , that every `x` elements of it, will contains a dictionary for 1 category from each . This is some kind of *equal distribution* .

so first x in the new array created are :

```
1. dic1 (categoryA)
2. dic2 (categoryb)
3. dic3 (categoryC)
x. dic4 (categoryD)
```

Than the next x elements :

```
x+1. dic1 (categoryA)
x+2. dic1 (categoryb)
x+3. dic1 (categoryC)
x+4. dic1 (categoryD)
```

till i finish all the elements in the original array .(last ones dont have to exactly fill the x categories since i dont know if 300± is divided by x . )

I am looping on the array in the traditional way, but i was looking for a smart fast way to do that with `NSSortDescriptor` ,or combined, to make it better .
Thanks .

EDIT:

I did this.

```
    loop over ([originalArray count] / x)  times 
     {
       loop over x categories
      {
        get from original an element with this category
        save it to new array
        remove it from original(or a copy created for this)

      }

    }
than just add what left in original, to the new .
```

Comment: I came up with this: http://pastebin.com/hB6xbFav I couldn't get rid of the `for loop`, but since I don't know how you previous too "heavy" code looks like, I can't say if it seems better. You may also be inspired by it. I didn't post it as an answer, 'cause I have the feeling that it can be better, but it may give a few tips/hints.

Comment: thanks very much for your answer. It seems that my code is much shorter, see what i did in my edit let me know what you think about it. thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

here is my answer to anyone who face something similar, i think its pretty simple, any advice for a change will be appreciated  :

```
    -(void)distributeEqualiy:(NSMutableArray*)data
    {

        NSMutableArray *copy=[[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithArray:data];
        NSMutableArray *new=[[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
        int numCat=[[Globals sharedGlobals].categories count];
        int loop=[copy count] / numCat ;


        for(int k=0;k<loop;k++)
        {
            for(NSString *category in  [Globals sharedGlobals].categories)
            {

                //get some data with the category
                int toAdd=-1;
                for(NSDictionary *dic in copy)
                {
                    if([[dic objectForKey:@"category"] isEqualToString:category])
                    {
                        toAdd= [copy indexOfObject:dic];
                        break;
                     }
                }
                //add and remove only if found
                 if(toAdd>-1)
                {
                  [new addObject:[copy objectAtIndex:toAdd]     ];
                  [copy removeObject:[copy objectAtIndex:toAdd] ];
                }

            }

         }

//results
        for(NSDictionary *dic in new)
            NSLog(@"%@",[dic objectForKey:@"category"]);

    }
```

Now what is left (you can't be sure that 'loop' is in the exact size of the number of each category in the array- for example array full of categoryA-will left you with some unsorted data )  you can take and add to 'new' , or loop over it and arrange it again,according to its categories .